# Pod framework not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Having issues linking a framework into my project in xcode. 
It looks like it cannot find libPods-tesseractOcrSample.a but not sure how to link this correctly.

Please see below

[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the folder/group of the header file you're importing. The is inside the folder/group named `TesseractOCRiOS`.

So instead of

```
#import <TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.h>
```

It should be:

```
#import <TesseractOCRiOS/TesseractOCR.h>
```

Sometimes you can try importing libraries like so:

```
@import TesseractOCR;
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help, this didn't work however. Also, this is a React Native project if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the pod folder from Project's directory and then reinstall the pod. That might help :)